# Mocking Reference Parameter with RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pass-by-reference, rhino-mocks

I my code, I have the following call:

```
 string proposed=string.Empty;
 validator.IsValid(arg0, arg1, ref proposed);
```

I stub the validator in my test and want that stub to alter the content of the referenced `proposed` string variable. I tried setting the value of the argument in the WhenCalled-Handler, but this shows no effect.

```
validatorStub.Stub(x => x.IsValid(arg0, arg1, ref proposed))
                                            .IgnoreArguments()
                                            .WhenCalled(invocation =>
                                            {
                                                invocation.Arguments[2] = "123456"; 
                                            }).Throw(new ValidationException(string.Empty));
```

Is this possible with Rhino at all? Unfortunately, I have no way of editing that validator...

**EDIT:** Thanks to @FireAlkazar, I understood that I had to better illustrate my test situtation:

Method Code:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
   public string Arg0{get;set;}
   public string Arg1{get;set;}
   public IValidator Validator {get;set;}

   public bool Validate()
   {
      string proposal = string.Empty;
      try
      {
         if (Validator.IsValid(Arg0, Arg1, ref proposal)) return true;
      }
      catch (ValidationException ex)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proposal))
         {
            // I want to test this section of code
         }
      }
      return false;
   }                   
}
```

Test Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Validate_ValidatorProposes_ReturnsTrue()
{
    string arg0 = "123456789";
    string arg1 = "201208150030551ABC";
    string prop = "123456";

    ClassUnderTest testInstance = new ClassUnderTest();
    testInstance.Arg0 = arg0;
    testInstance.Arg1 = arg1;

    IValidator validatorStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IValidator>();
    validatorStub.Stub(x => x.IsValid(Arg<string>.Is.Equal(arg0),
                                      Arg<string>.Is.Equal(arg1),
                                      ref Arg<string>.Ref(Is.Anything(), prop).Dummy))
                 .Throw(new ValidationException(string.Empty));
    testInstance.Validator = validatorStub;

    bool actual = testInstance.Validate();

    Assert.IsFalse(actual);
}
```

Still, when I step through this, I see that the ValidatorStub throws the exception i expect it to throw, but never sets the ref parameter.

---

**EDIT :** [This branch of RhinoMocks](https://github.com/alaendle/rhino-mocks) uses a newer version of Castle Core, which solves the issue. The author was kind enough to inform me about this via Google Groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation for this case [Rhino Mocks 3.5 Out and Ref arguments](http://ayende.com/wiki/%28X%281%29S%28honszezftusqh14yyppvsqxt%29%29/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino%20Mocks%203.5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#OutandRefarguments)

Looks like you will have something like

```
validatorStub.Stub(x => x.IsValid(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything, ref Arg<string>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Anything(), "123456").Dummy));

string testRefValue = "";
validatorStub.IsValid("1", "2", ref testRefValue);
Assert.AreEqual("123456", testRefValue);
```

**EDIT:**
Had an investigation on your case. Final result is no, can't do that in latest version of Rhino Mocks(3.6). The reason is a bug in old version of Castle.DynamycProxy, that is used by mocks.

Proof:
[fix bug: ref & out parameter can not received if Proxied Method throw an](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core-READONLY/pull/14)
this fix adds lines to *Castle.Core/DynamicProxy/Generators/InvocationTypeGenerator.cs* like this:

```
bool hasByRefArguments = false;

//...

if (hasByRefArguments) 
{
    invokeMethodOnTarget.CodeBuilder.AddStatement(new TryStatement());
}

//...
```

Add in reflector for Rhino.Mocks.dll there is no extra handling for hasByRefArguments case(see same file InvocationTypeGenerator.cs).

Comment: thanks for giving me that link (+1). `ValidatorStub` is a Dependency I want to Stub, so I can test my class under test. What you did was testing the Stub itself. I will update the question to make this clear!

Comment: thanks a lot for your investigation! Since this issue is 2 years old, I don't there will be a new Build that fixes it...

Comment: Updated the original post with solution

Comment: Cool, pretty quick reaction on bug